# Making changes to branch after code review in git

Tags: git, github, branching-and-merging, github-codereviews

I have a branch `feature/my-changes` which I have made changes to. I pushed these changes, created a pull request, and have gotten feedback on my changes through a code review. My question is: Now that I see the changes I need to make in github (from code review comments), do I simply go back to my code editor and make those changes in my branch, make a new commit, and push again? Or should I be "checking out" a revision of my branch's history and make edits there? I'm not really sure how to proceed after this code review...

Comment: You’d usually just make the changes on the branch you’re working on, commit and push. Once everyone’s happy you merge back to your develop branch

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to deal with this is checking out the branch `feature/my-changes`, then make the changes according to the review comments, create a new commit and push your branch.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.Since you have not yet merged the branch (also if it is merged) you can clearly make changes in the same branch and then commit and you can use the same Pull Request again for Review and merge.